# Can I delete initial ubuntu user on Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, security, user-management, users

Ubuntu installer create by default an initial user called `ubuntu` (that it's also a sudoers), as explained [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/user-management.html).

On my server I have created another sudoer (with a less common name) and I would like to delete the default/initial `ubuntu` user to improove security.

Can I safely delete/remove this user or is used by the OS?

Comment: Are you sure that such a user is created? On my Ubuntu 18.04 server no user named `ubuntu` exists (checked with `cat /etc/passwd | grep 'ubuntu'`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes - on a server the Ubuntu user is not needed (and, to the my knowledge) is not created by default. I suspect you did not use a server image to create the install - did you maybe convert a live image?

Of-course, you do need a user who can log in and become root (as I understand you have done).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However yes, I don't use a server image. I have a VPS and the SO installation is automated and managed by the provider.